# Часть кода, которая должна постоянно работать

Tags: python, telebot, бот

Я работаю над телеграм-ботом, и мне нужно что бы шла постоянная проверка времени: если настаёт указанное время, то бот отправляет ссылку. Пытался сделать через модуль os.path, но почему-то не корректно работает. Возможно у Вас есть альтернативный вариант.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте threading и schedule

```
import telebot
import threading
import schedule

...

def job():
  print('Привет, это задача job')


def runBot():
  bot.polling()


def mainJob():
    schedule.every().day.do(job)
    while True:
      schedule.run_pending()
      time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runBot)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=mainJob)
    # starting thread 1 
    t1.start() 
    # starting thread 2 
    t2.start()
```

Команда `schedule.every().day.do(job)` будет запускать функцию job каждый день. Вместо day можете подставить свои данные.

Если хотите, чтобы оно работало раз в день в какое-то время, то прописывайте `schedule.every().day.at("14:00").do(job)`.

С минутами и часами тоже самое `schedule.every().hour.at(":30").do(job)` Тогда функция job будет срабатывать каждый раз в 30 минут, в 15:30, 16:30, 17:30 и т.д.

Comment: Понял! Спасибо Вам большое!